# Are there any python implementations of GGP games or how to use game logic written in GDL in python?

Tags: python, game-ai, combinatorial-games

I'm writing a General Game Playing (GGP) AI in python. I'd like to test it on some GGP games. So are there any python implementations of GGP games?

I found in http://games.ggp.org/base games written in Game Description Language (GDL). How to use them in python if it is possible to do so?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE! What is "GDL" and "GGP"? You should use the long version of these terms the first time you use them, so that everyone knows what the abbreviation exactly refers to. Moreover, it's not fully clear how your question is related to AI and is on-topic according to our on-topic page. Please, have a look at https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question now. I think its on-topic as it comes under developmental aspects of AI.

Comment: Your question may be more appropriate for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, but I am not sure it's on-topic there too.

Comment: I'm not sure if the specific question asking for python-based solutions is on-topic, but GGP/GDL have certainly been big AI topics and would be on-topic (it's academic game AI research stuff, probably wouldn't be suitable for gamedev @nbro). To respond to the question; most GDL people I know use Java/C++, sometimes Prolog. Python is probably way too slow to be useful for GDL. Except maybe if you first do the expensive parts in C++, and then wrap Python around it (this seems to be done in https://github.com/richemslie/galvanise_zero/tree/dev/src/ggpzero I think)

Comment: Personally I'd recommend using Ludii (https://ludii.games/) instead of GDL these days, but I'm a part of the Ludii group myself so that recommendation may not be 100% objective :)

Comment: @DennisSoemers Thanks, I'll check out ludii.